# MongoDB projection to return child objects as columns

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and I have a mongodb document like this

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "title": "abc123",
    "author": {
        "last": "zzz",
        "first": "aaa",
        "address": {
            "street": "stvalue",
            "city": "NewYork"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using MongoDB Java client and trying to convert the above document as

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "title": "abc123",
    "author_last": "zzz",
    "author_first": "aaa",
    "author_address_street": "stvalue",
    "author_address_city": "New York"
}
```

Is this possible using MongoDB Java client using MongoDB query without modifying the result in Java.

***Update***

Since it is not possible to convert to required format in MongoQuery, I have to change my mind and add some Java code to get the required format.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is exactly. Can't you just read the values you want from the db in Java code using the Java client, then perform the transformations in Java code, and then write it back to the db?

Comment: I just want to convert the child object into columns

Comment: @bot, I have formatted my question. I want the result as above when data is returned from mongodb, instead of doing it in Java.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** We cleaned up the comments, yet again. If you feel to continue to discuss stuff not related to the question at hand, then take it to chat.  The comments should be about the question, not unrelated nonsense.

Comment: @NeilLunn - Perhaps if you hadn't been insulting and condescending to bot, they wouldn't have reacted in kind. This is your last warning. If I see you insult another user on this site, I will suspend your account for a year. Do I make myself clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Java implementation which will convert all child objects into an HashMap

```
private List<Map<String,String>> mapReduce(AggregationOutput output){
    List<Map<String,String>> out = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
        Map<String,String> map = ConvertDBObjectToMap(result, "");
        out.add(map);
    }
    return out;
}


private Map<String,String> ConvertDBObjectToMap(DBObject result, String parent)
{
    String prefix = parent == "" ? "" : parent + "_";

    Map<String,String> out = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] keys = result.keySet().toArray(new String[result.keySet().size()]);
    for(String key : keys)
    {
        Object obj = result.get(key);
        if(obj instanceof BasicDBObject)
        {
            out.putAll(ConvertDBObjectToMap((BasicDBObject) obj, prefix + key));
        }
        else if(obj instanceof String)
        {
            out.put(prefix + key,(String)obj);
        }
        else if(obj instanceof  Date){
            out.put(prefix + key,obj.toString());
        }
        else{
            out.put(prefix + key,obj.toString());
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a matter of which "client" or "driver library" you use, as much as the only way to do this is via the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to "alter the fields" in response. It is your most practical way of doing so:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "title": 1,
        "author_last": "$author.last",
        "author_first": "$author.first",
        "author_address_street": "$author.address.street",
        "author_address_city": "$author.address.city"
    }}
])
```

Very easy to translate into any language, but shows you the basic principles.

Very Java(esque) then the syntax becomes (in basic driver):

```js
BasicDBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project",
    new BasicDBObject( "title", 1 )
        .append( "author_last", "$author.last" )
        .append( "author_first", "$author.first" )
        .append( "author_address_street", "$author.address.street" ),
        .append( "author_address_city", "$author.address.city" )
);

collection.aggregate(project);
```

---

If you cannot just specify the keys in this way then your only real option on the server is mapReduce. Much in the same way as above, it might be better to do this in the client response:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var item = {};
        var id = this._id;
        delete this._id;

        var obj = this;

        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) { 
            if ( typeof(obj[key]) == "object" ) {
                Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach(function(subKey) {
                     if ( typeof(obj[key][subkey] == "object" ) {
                         Object.keys(obj[key][subKey]).forEach(function(subSub) {
                             item[key + "_" + subKey + "_" + subSub] = obj[key][subKey][subSub];
                         });
                     } else {
                          item[key + "_" + subKey] = obj[key][subKey];
                     }
                });
            } else {
                item[key] = obj[key];
            }
        });

        emit( id, item );
    },
    function() {}, // no reduction required
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

I think that makes sense, but I'm just typing it so possible syntax problems, but the idea should be relevant. You might also need something more complex depending on your actual data.

Point is, that you need the JavaScript execution to "traverse" your document on the server to use this method.

Otherwise, just do the same in code since you are iterating a cursor anyway.

Comment: This is not possible for me, because of the dynamic nature of the document, if in future if a new field is added to address, then I have to modify the query, which I can't.

Comment: @TheIndianProgrammmer Do not understand what you are saying. There  are no "wildcard" values in any MongoDB query expressions.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for taking time into this question, I already tried what you have mentioned earlier, My requirement to flattern the document with no object chain, all child objects should be part of the root document. I cannot hard code any fields in the query except the parent, since child objects may change any time.

Comment: @TheIndianProgrammmer Ouch! There really isn't practical way to do that other than using the JavaScript evaluation of mapReduce. I can update with an example, but it is usually best to do in client code. Wait a few minutes and I will update to explain.

Comment: @TheIndianProgrammmer Sorry, took more than just a few minutes with other responses considered. The edit should explain the basic points.

Comment: Thanks, Here is my implementation in Java as you suggested to do in Java. I will add it as a new answer.

Comment: @TheIndianProgrammmer Really? Why? Added nothing but JavaScript code here ( which you cannot alter) so I don't see what you can add other than client processing which is what you didn't want to do in the first place. Seems like a definitive answer to me, You can only copy for your own answer and I don't see how that helps people.

Comment: How would I call this javaScript from my MongoDB Java Client.